# Prove limit law

Tags: limit, proof

7. Let f and g be functions with domain (−∞, ∞). Assume that lim x→0 f(x) = 3 and lim x→0 g(x) = 2.

Prove, directly from the ε − δ definition of limit, that
lim x→0 [f (x) + 2g(x)] = 7.

One of the solution is

Solution: Since lim x→0 f(x) = 3, we can take εf = ε/2, and we know there exists some δf > 0 such that if 0<|x|<δf then |f(x) -3| < ε/2.

But I don't know how to get εf = ε/2.

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a math problem not a programming problem. Belongs to https://math.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about mathematics, not programming.